# ListViewItem not receiving OnMouseDownEvent and ListView not calling selection changed callback

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have the following:

```
 <ListView SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIdx}" SelectionChanged="ItemsList_SelectionChanged"  MinHeight="200" x:Name="ItemsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Background="Yellow" Grid.Row="1">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <!--  note that the list mode is wide enough to force a wrap to each new line  -->
                            <WrapPanel Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ItemsList}" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:Item/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListView>
```

Each individual 'Item' xaml has mousedown callbacks which aren't called but OnMouseOver is.

ItemsList_SelectionChanged is never called either.

The item xaml is pretty basic:

```
<ListViewItem x:Class="Controls.Item"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Controls.Controls.Item.ViewModel"
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="50"
             Width="50"
             Height="50"
             Background="Blue"
             Padding="0,0,0,0"
         MouseLeftButtonDown="ListViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown">
   <!--  <Grid>
        < ! - - <Label IsHitTestVisible="False"  Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Background="Pink"  Content="{Binding Label}"/> - - >
    </Grid> -->
</ListViewItem>
```

Like I said before, 'ListViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown' doens't get called either but if there's a MouseOver event that does get called.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its because the parent ListViewItem or ListView itself handle the PreviewMouseDown event and mark it as Handled="True".

I have 2 suggestions for you:

1. Do not use ListViewItem as the ItemTemplate. One is being created to wrap your ItemTemplate anyway.
2. Write a Behavior to use on your ItemTemplate's Content. The Behavior should register to PreviewMouseDown event and raise a Command(with Binding to it from the ListView's DataContext).